# problem with c about issue with clang 7 error?

Tags: c

Picture of code

[image]

I have a problem with clang 7 error, I don't know what the issue is? Why is clang -o hello hello.c not working? I have already tried twice and the error repeated itself so I am unsure why the clang -o hello hello.c is not working.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j9as.png - link to picture for code

Comment: Just FYI `C#` and `C` are different languages =) Also better post code and errors as text, so it would be easier to help you

Comment: Code should be directly inserted as text, not as images. However, the problem is that you already have a directory named "hello". Delete it.

Comment: post code instead of image it will be easy to debug

Answer (score 1):

Read the messages. The `clang` command told you:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file hello: Is a directory
```

The “/usr/bin/ld:” part says the specific program “/usr/bin/ld” (which is the linker; it links object files into an executable file) is giving you this message.

The “cannot open output file hello” part says it cannot output the file named “hello”.

The “Is a directory” part says why there is a problem: “hello” is a directory, meaning it exists and is a directory, not a regular file, so it cannot be opened like a regular file. The linker wants to open it as a regular file so that it can write to it.

To fix this, either remove or rename the directory named “hello” (check what is in it first, to see if you want it) or use a different output file name in the `clang` command.